# pass integer from listview to another activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I want to pass the integer (id) from listview (when it is clicked) to TheEndActivity.java . But my code cant retrieve the integer properly.

UsernameList.java (it is the class where the integer comes from)

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {         
    Intent i = new Intent( this, TheEndActivity.class ); 
    i.putExtra( "int", (int)id);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "id value "+id);
    startActivity( i );

    Intent intent = new Intent(UsernameList.this, QuizAppActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

TheEndActivity.java (Its the class where i need to pass the integer here. it is created inside onCreate method)

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    final int number = i.getIntExtra("int", -1);
```

and i need to use the integer (id) which i save it into database (the operation is done in TheEndActivity.java)

```
finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        helper.insertMark(currentGame.getRight(), number );
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "id value: " + number );
        Intent i = new Intent(TheEndActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**Solved**

The problem is i called 2 activities. Thank you guys

Comment: I don't understand, why do you call `startActivity()` two times?

Comment: Are you sure you want `id` or `position` ?

Comment: why don't you pass `long` instead of `int`?

Comment: Try to remove the `final` from int number and check if you receive the integer corectly

Comment: @LadaRider : because after complete the QuizAppActivity i need to save score in TheEndActivity.

Comment: @Adil: because the id i need to save it later on in sqlite where i defined it as integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem seems to be in calling 2 startActivities. 
Are TheEndActivity and QuizAppActivity both activities?

1. You have to change TheEndActivity into an IntentService or AsyncTask if its something doing background activity like saving things into database.
2. If it's not, then launch only TheEndActivity and allow user to navigate to QuizAppActivity from there.
3. Also try changing
   Intent i = new Intent( this, TheEndActivity.class ); to 
   Intent i = new Intent( UsernameList.this, TheEndActivity.class );

Comment: So if i want to save the integer that is passed, i need to change it to IntentService? Can i just simply make it as option 2?

Comment: Thank you @chandra finally i just call 1 activity then i access the value from tht activity.

Comment: @Kumisku, for your question on point no. 3, if its ListActivity, then you need not mention UsernameList.this but if it's activity with custom list then it's required I think. Anyway glad that I was able to help you.

Comment: @Kumisku, nope for passing values between activities you can always use intents. I was talking about storing data in database. It's always better to do that in asynctask or intentservices.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `startActivity` with an `intent` that doesn't have the int as an extra.

Comment: @ChandraMohan: The one that is executed is the second one, which doesn't have the extra.